# Getting adb working with my galaxy s3 to debug my app

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I've managed to turn on developer features (debugging mode), got adb running, it recognizes my device when I plug it into usb (woohoo!), but I can't seem to cd into my app's directly when I `adb shell` into my device. Is there a way to get root access, or a better way to debug my app?

**Most importantly** how can I view console.logs?

Comment: 1. Do you know about DDMS?http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html 2. Are you using logcat? http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: Thanks for trying man. I got this: `The standalone version of DDMS is deprecated. Please use Android Device Monitor (tools/monitor) instead.` No matter what I do I keep hitting brick walls. The closer I get to getting a feature working the worse it fails. So sad : ( I'm just trying to get started with Cordova (Phonegap), but have no real luck.